# jquery: detect change in any element which falls under a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Ok so I have many checkboxes on a page. I need to detect when any one of these checkboxes are clicked / changed so I can run a function. Let's say that function simply prints the ID of the checkbox to the console. Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/4ody743b/

I'm trying to give each checkbox input the same class `myCheckboxes` so I can just detect a change in that class, identify exactly which input I clicked using the `this` keywork and then run the function (not sure if this works or not). I'm also curious if there's a better solution without using the `this` keyword. I'm very new to Javascript so sorry if this question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First question:

There is an event for that, it called `change` event. You can listen to it like this:

```
$('.myCheckboxes').on('change', function() {
    // ...
});
```

or:

```
$('.myCheckboxes').change(function() {
    // ...
});
```

**Example:**

```js
function printID (element) {
  console.log(element.id)
}

$('.myCheckboxes').change(function() {
    printID(this); // this is only accessible within this anounimous function
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="0" class="myCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="myCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" class="myCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="3" class="myCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" class="myCheckboxes">
```

**Note:**

Since `printID` is not the callback for the event listener (it's not the function passed when assigning the event listener), it won't have the keyword `this` bound to the checkbox, so when call it from the real function of the event listener, you'll have to pass the element as parameter. If you want to assign `printID` as the callback of the event listener so you can use `this` inside `printID` then you have to pass a reference to it like this:

```
$('.myCheckboxes').change(printID);
```

now you can use `this` inside `printID` like this:

```
function printID() {
  var checkbox = this;
  console.log(checkbox.id);
}
```

## Second Question:

If you don't want to use `this` which is the best one, you can use the event parameter passed to the event listener function and access the element using `event.target` like this:

```
$('.myCheckboxes').on('change', function(ev) {
    var element = ev.target; // the same as this
    // ...
});
```

**Example:**

```js
function printID (element) {
  console.log(element.id)
}

$('.myCheckboxes').change(function(ev) {
    printID(ev.target); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="0" class="myCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="myCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" class="myCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="3" class="myCheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" class="myCheckboxes">
```

**Edit:**

The code you want to execute along with any event listening should be wrapped inside the load event callback like this:

```
$(function() { // this is the load callback (jQuery shortcut for $(document).ready)
    // print the values of the already checked boxes here

    // any thing you want to do on window load should be here

    // anything that have something to do with the DOM (event listenening, changing element, deleting them, ...) should be here

    $('.myCheckboxes').change(function() { // this is also should be here
        // ...
    });
});
```

as a matter of fact all the code that is interacting with the DOM should be inside the load callback (**SAFER**). Function definitions could be outside but the fetching of DOM elements, removing them, changing their attributes and text contents ... should wait for the DOM to be loaded.

```
$(function() {
    $("someElement").remove();            // OK
    $("otherEements").each(someFunction); // OK
});

function someFunction() {  // OK (even if its outside, because this is a function definition it doesn't mean it's going to be executed right away)
    // ...
}

$("yetAnotherElement").addClass("someClass"); // NOT OK: if the code is before the body (if the js code is in the head of the html), then yetAnotherElement is not there yet so the class is never set on it, this line is better be inside the load event

someFunction(); // OK if someFuntion doesn't do anything with the DOM
                // NOT OK if the someFunction is doing something with the DOM, because we are calling it from outside the load event which mean that there is a good chance that the DOM is not loaded yet and the element someFunction trying to access or modify are not yet parsed or created
```

Further reading: [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), and [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Follow up question: what if some of the boxes are checked on the page load (and I want to print these values to the console when the page loads as I do when they are changed). Do I need to create 2 different functions for this ($(document).ready() and .change()) or is there one function that works for this case?

Comment: @jcmetz21 Sorry for the late reply! You'll have to do it on window load! And the change function should be also wrapped inside the window load callback which then you have just to put your code there. I edited my answer see the section **Edit:** above!

Comment: Incredible explanation! My last question would be why does w3 schools still use $(document).ready() in their [jQuery examples](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_examples.asp)? Is one better than the other or is w3 schools outdated? (Sorry for the delayed reply - was on vacation)

Comment: w3 schools ignore a lot of important stuff. I recommend refering to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for more details. And http://api.jquery.com/ for jQuery's docs.

Comment: w3schools is just hideous. Look at the docs for `forEach` on [**w3schools**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) and on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and judge for your self!